# Can't add accessibility identifier for HereMapSDK elements in UI Testing

Tags: ios, swift, here-api, heremaps, heremaps-ios-sdk

I am writing UITest cases for HereMapSDK elements (NMAMapCircle, NMAMapPolyline, NMAMapMarker), but I can't add `accessibility identifier` for it.

As I can see in SDK, there isn't any property for adding `accessibility identifier`.

Can anyone suggest, how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please check this example for Unit Testing : 

https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/explore/ios/UnitTesting/UnitTests

Answer (score 0):

This is related to HSDK 3.x.

please check this example for Unit Testing :

https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/explore/ios/UnitTesting/UnitTests

Could you please use sdk 4 as HERE SDK 3.x is not being supported any longer.

We have latest HERE mobile SDK  4.x.

link to sdk 4.x https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-explore/4.12.4.0/dev_guide/index.html